# Mesh Wifi Router Network for a Small Village

Tags: telecommunication, wireless-communication, wifi

I was wondering if its possible to create mesh network of WiFi for relatively large area? I am talking about the size of small village (**~20km2**). The idea is to use centralized connectivity with enough bandwith, then distribute them using mesh wifi router (like Google WiFi) for every X radius

Is this a pipe dream? What would likely be the obstacles?

Mesh-type should be used to maintain just single SSID over a whole network

> Google Wifi: We recommend a maximum of five Wifi points in a single
> mesh set up

**Edit:** I am just not aware if there's any limit for this case to happen, and why Google Wifi even have that 5 limit value while theoretically to my knowledge, as long as it's placed nearby to each other, wouldn't it could be used to expand the signal unlimited time? I just couldn't find answer elsewhere. Any input is highly appreciated

Comment: Cross posted: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/538776/152903

Comment: It is widely discouraged to use unlimited hops since each hop closer to the source will have more traffic, and since you are talking about 20km2 that’s going to be a lot of traffic. Ubiquiti does have some solutions, like point to point beam transmittors. Try demo.ui.com and choose outlets at castle rock as site. There might be other capable brands but I’m familliar with unifi and am pretty sure there’s a solution to be found there.

Comment: @Ananas_hoi "since each hop closer to the source will have more traffic" could elaborate this? Since it'll be distributed evenly throughout the area - not sure if traffic become any issue here as long as sufficient plan is used

Comment: How does the signal get back to the centralized connectivity - does it go from wi-fi to wi-fi to wi-fi, or does it go from wi-fi to cable and then get all the way back using the cable?

Comment: @gijoe if I have time tomorrow I will see if I can draw something for you, that illustrates it. However, I think more than enough resources exist online that cover this subject.

Comment: @user253751 Yes "wifi to wifi to wifi" (router amplify signal and so on so forth), cabling only in central source

Comment: @Ananas_hoi I might just unable to use proper keyword then? Any guidance would be helpful, couldn't find any close to my case

Comment: @gijoe I don't have any hard numbers for you, but I will point out that wired connections are considered much better, so you should consider using them where possible.

Comment: @Solar Mike the link has been removed now.

Comment: @Owl glad you are tracking my comments from a year ago. I don't, I find it more rewarding to answer questions...